# Get a diff from between two string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a two strings and need to get just a diff between them like this

```
dim st1 As String = "SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 FROM TEST"
dim st2 As String = "SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM TEST"
```

I need to compare and show that "`st2` does not have `,C4,C5`"

so I try to use

```
Dim differenceQuery = st1.Except(st2)
lbldiff.Text = "st2 not have "
For Each name As String In differenceQuery
    lbldiff.Text += name & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

but this only shows `4 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution to solved my problem

```
   Dim diff As List(Of String)
        Dim set1 As IEnumerable(Of String) = sql.ToLower.Split(","c).Distinct()
        Dim set2 As IEnumerable(Of String) = answer.ToLower.Split(","c).Distinct()
        If set2.Count() > set1.Count() Then
            diff = set2.Except(set1).ToList()
        Else
            diff = set1.Except(set2).ToList()
        End If
        If diff IsNot Nothing AndAlso diff.Count <> 0 Then
            lbldiff.Text = "you have a problem on : <br />"
            For Each li As String In diff
                lbldiff.Text += li & " <br /> "
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for you, test and edit it if you need.
 This is C# but you can translate it to vb i think ( not the best way to achieve this and not optimize at all )

```
        private List<string> CompareSQLString(string t1,string t2,string table)
    {

        List<string> res = new List<string>();

        t1 = t1.Replace("SELECT", "").Replace("FROM", "").Replace(table,"").Replace("  ", string.Empty);
        t2 = t2.Replace("SELECT", "").Replace("FROM", "").Replace(table, "").Replace("  ", string.Empty);

        List<string> res1 = new List<string>(t1.Split(','));
        List<string> res2 = new List<string>(t2.Split(','));


            foreach(string val in res1)
            {
                if(!res2.Contains(val))
                {
                    res.Add(val);
                }
            }


        return res;
    }
```

You can use it like this :

```
        string t1 = "SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 FROM TEST";
        string t2 = "SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM TEST";
        List<string> test = CompareSQLString(t1, t2,"TEST");
```

test will contains two values, C4 and C5

EDIT : Don't hesitate to ask comments or explanations

Comment: sorry for my not clear questions :) I need to compare not just a SELECT command it's possible with Create insert or any other command to compare between them. Thanks but I found the solution to solved my problem.